# Debug build works fine, Release build breaks?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows-store, uwp

Trying to publish my UWP app. I'm able to build Release versions fine (I was actually able to push to the Store), but my app crashes as soon as it's launched. But the debug works fine?

I'm getting this error when debugging a Release build:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x55BA32F9 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in AppName.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x00A12450, 0x00000002).
```

And these errors in Event Viewer if I launch it outside of VS:

1st:

```
Activation of app AppName failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

2nd:

```
Faulting application name: AppName.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x560c53bd
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16431, time stamp: 0x55c9b90a
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x007132f9
Faulting process id: 0x1e38
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0fbcba39fec70
Faulting application path: C:\Development\AppName\AppName\bin\x86\Release\AppX\AppName.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 5c74b39d-98e4-4e89-b2ec-c81cbd5383d1
Faulting package full name: AppName
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I don't get any errors or warnings on Debug.

Comment: 1) Do you have/have you looked at the crash dump? 2) When you launch the release build with the debugger attached, does the exception happen at a specific location?

Comment: I have the dump, but I don't know what to look for. It breaks as soon as it launches. http://i.imgur.com/gBkJuxc.png

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the Debug log: http://pastebin.com/zv8C0b12

Comment: You may be missing a **capability** in your app manifest. I've had the same issue where I hadn't enabled a capability, but the app runs fine until it's published.

Comment: @MikeEason I enabled all of the capabilities and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with Entity Framework when it is compiled in .NET Native. I had to switch to SQLite for what I was using it for. Seems to work fine now.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3293

Answer (score 0):

Add some code to the app.xaml.cs files unhandled exception event to send the error text to a web service or something like google analytics so you can see what is happening